# Private member page

Tags: customization, membership, members

I need to make a private page for subscribers in my Wordpress website
I don’t want to use plugins so I’m asking what is better, add the capability to subscribers to read private pages or maybe create a custom page template with conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it without plugins, you just have to allow `subscribers` to see Private posts and pages, depending on what you want, so you have to put this code in your **functions.php**

```
$subRole = get_role( 'subscriber' );
$subRole->add_cap( 'read_private_posts' );
$subRole->add_cap( 'read_private_pages' );
```

And then simply create a private post or page and it will works as expected. Tested.

Comment: Great that is what I was thinking, i suppose it is a secure solution as well.

Comment: Also do you suggest to use the hook wp_roles_init?

Comment: I don't see why would you need it: "After the roles have been initialized, allow plugins to add their own roles."

Comment: I read on Wordpress.org NB: This setting is saved to the database, so it might be better to run this on theme/plugin activation

Comment: Since you don't want to add new roles I don't see why you need it.